# No fields in appearing ssrs dataset - dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm trying to run this through SSRS using the database name as  @CATALOG parameter but the field list won't populate. Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
DECLARE @SQLScript AS NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @SQLScript = 
'USE ' +@CATALOG + CHAR(13) +
'SELECT
    LD.ProvSpecMon_A AS Dept,
    LD.ProvSpecMon_C AS SubjArea,
    LD.ProvSpecMon_B AS CourseCode,
    L.LearnRefNumber AS PersonCode,
    CASE 
        WHEN L.PlanEEPHours + L.PlanLearnHours >= 540 THEN 'FT' 
        ELSE 'PT'
    END AS LearnerType,
    LD.AimType,
    LD.LearnAimRef AS LearningAim,
    AIM.LearnAimRefTitle AS LearningAimTitle,
    EFA.OnProgPayment,
    EFA.StartFund
FROM Valid.Learner L
INNER JOIN Valid.LearningDelivery LD
    ON LD.LearnRefNumber = L.LearnRefNumber
LEFT JOIN Rulebase. DV_Learner AGE
    ON AGE.LearnRefNumber = L.LearnRefNumber
LEFT JOIN Rulebase.EFA_LEARNER EFA
    ON EFA.LearnRefNumber = L.LearnRefNumber
LEFT JOIN Rulebase.EFALearningDeliveryLARSInput AIM
    ON AIM.AimSeqNumber = LD.AimSeqNumber
    AND AIM.LearnRefNumber = LD.LearnRefNumber
WHERE
    EFA.StartFund = 1
    AND LD.AimType = 5
ORDER BY
    L.LearnRefNumber'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLScript
```

Comment: What's the error? What tables are you using and what are their structures? What output are you expecting?

Comment: Try running the query with a hardcoded catalog, check if it works to discard parameter population error.

Comment: It works fine with a hardcoded catalog. I'm not getting error message but the field list won't display in the dataset.

Comment: Catalog must be set at datasource not dataset level.

Comment: I have a couple of other ssrs reports that work with the Catalog as a datasource but they don't use the EXECUTE sp_executesql just EXEC @SQLScript. I've tried this with this report and still can't get the field list to appear.  I've just slightly amended these reports as some of the field names had changed.

Comment: Recommended reading: [How to use dynamic data sources in your SSRS report](http://www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2012/08/how-to-use-dynamic-data-sources-in-your.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parametrize your catalog you have to parametrize your connection string.

In datasource properties select `Embedded connection` and put a connection string expression with your parameter.

[image]

You can use parameters in the connection string:

```
="Data Source=" & Parameters!ServerName.Value & ";Initial Catalog=" & Parameters!Catalog.Value
```